# minimum data rate required to stream a video of resolution 1920 *1080 pixels with a 25/s frame rate.

Tags: networking

I just want to ask what would be the minimum data rate required if we need to stream a video of resolution 1920*1080 pixels with a 25/s frame rate.

I tried doing it using the data rate access formula i.e.

data rate = Amount of data/time.

is that ok?

Comment: Yes, but your `data` in `data/time` is not `resolution-height * resolution-width * bits/pixel`. The data usually is compressed, so it completely depends on the encoder and the parameters it's using to determine the data rate.

Comment: yeah I think so too. I was using the wrong formula to do it. I just read an article so I think I have done it. thanks for replying tho

Answer (score 1):

The data rate for uncompressed video in bit/s is `(h[px]*w[px]*depth[bit]*framerate[1/s])+overhead` which is around 1,25 Gbit/s.

Uncompressed data is most often not needed - images can be compressed quite nicely without much of a visual impact.

From my experience with actual TV broadcast workflow:

ProRes HQ will give an Edit-Quality image at ca. 110 Mbit/s consuming amazingly little CPU (less than a modern core), H.264 will give a Broadcast-Quality image at ca. 12 Mbit/s consuming ca. 2 modern CPU cores.

Comment: Thank You very much for answering. I guess I was using the wrong formula.

Answer (score 0):

The total size of the image I got is 1920*1080 pixels i.e. 11.8 MB
as the video was shot at 25 frames per sec 
so after copying 1 sec of data, the my drive  will have = 11.8 MB * 25 frames
= 295 MB space, so the data rate will be 295 MB/s.

I hope its right.